# Segue to another storyboard via interface builder

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

How do you create a segue between a view controller in one storyboard and a view controller in another storyboard?

Comment: There's [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18777627/2792531), but I don't want to count your question as a duplicate of this because I'm pretty sure there's a way to do it in Interface Builder these days.

Comment: There is appeared `storyboard references` in Xcode 7.

Comment: Storyboard reference fixed my problem thanks :)

Comment: in future if any buddy want to learn this then can refer [link](http://ioscodesample.blogspot.in/2015/10/storyboard-reference-in-ios-9.html)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Earlier it was not possible without code, but since Xcode 7, Apple has given us a powerful tool - `Storyboard References`.

What you need to do is to drag and drop this element to your initiating storyboard:

[image: storyboard reference]

In its options you select the proper storyboard and optionally (default it uses initial view controller) set its id.

[image: storyboard reference options]

Now you can define segue to this view controller as normal.

Please note that only normal segues work with iOS8. Relationship ones (like root, embed etc.) work only in iOS9.